# pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'MYID'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, webserver

I am running a flask web server on server A, and I need to access a SQL database in remote server B.

I am getting this error.

**pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'MYID'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")**﻿

Can someone help me??

Below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST']='IP OF SERVER B'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT']='SERVER B PORT NUMBER'
app.config['MYSQL_USER']='MYID'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']='MYPW'
app.config['MYSQL_DB']='DBNAME'
mysql=MySQL(app)
mysql.init_app(app)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()
    cur.execute('''SQLQUERY;''')
    rv=cur.fetchall()
    return str(rv)
```

Comment: have you granted privileges on user `MYID` for the schema `DBNAME` ?

Comment: thanks for the comment!!
is this what I am supposed to do?


`mysql > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBNAME.* TO 'MYID'@'localhost'`

Comment: yes using an account with grant privilege, see answer below

Answer (score 1):

Using a mysql client or console you should execute something like this:

```
grant all privileges on DBNAME.* to MYID@localhost identified by 'MYPW';
```

using a user with grant privilege (usually `root`).

Of course you can narrow down the privileges that you grant from: `all privileges` to let's say: `select,insert,update,delete`, depending on the case.

To access the console with root open a terminal window and write:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

and provide the password or for passwordless root:

```
mysql -uroot
```

In case you do not know the root password follow this guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

In case you are on a company/university workstation with no privileges to perform the above operation, ask from the administrator to grant the privileges.

Comment: thanks for the help !
when I try this,
`grant all privileges on DBNAME.* to MYID@localhost identified by 'MYPW';`

i get the following error
**ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'MYID'@'%' to database 'DBNAME'**

could this be due to administrator settings?

Comment: Have you used root for executing this?

Comment: no.. i did not have root access. won't work otherwise right?

Comment: No, but since it is a local installation, it is not difficult to have root access on mysql.

Comment: only the administrator (in the team) has the root access .. :(  so I don;t know the pw for the following login `mysql -uroot -p` . In this case I should contact the admin user right?

thank you so much ;D

Comment: The admin made the change, but still the same message. However using the following shell command in server A,  I was able to make the SQL  connection to server B.

`ssh -p PORTNUM -CNf -L3307:127.0.0.1:3306 MYID@SERVERB'sIP`
then
`mysql -u MYID -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -e "use DBNAME; $query;`

Wondering what's the difference with flask?

Comment: At flask use: `127.0.0.1` as host / `3307` as port, or ask from the admin to grant access to `MYID@your-ip`, to access directly the db server. The error pasted in the original post was misleading: `Access denied for user 'MYID'@'localhost'`, since you never mentioned anything about port-forwarding before.

Comment: the admin made the change as follows:
`grant all privileges on DBNAME.* to 'MYID'@'%' identified by 'MYPW';`
shouldn't this enable access from any ip?

Comment: any ip except from localhost! (which is what db server sees when `port-forwarding` is used). In mysql for localhost you need an additional grant.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = ...
```

to

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = ...
```

this applies to the rest as well:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST default is ‘localhost’
MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT default is 3306
MYSQL_DATABASE_USER default is None
MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD default is None
MYSQL_DATABASE_DB   default is None
MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET  default is ‘utf-8’
```

I had the same problem but this fixed it for me. Hope this helps you as well.
Look at the Flask MySQL reference [here](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage)